# Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code = 1, address = 0x13 Trying to get one property from my object

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to get identifier property from WSLanguage:NSManagerObject and I'm getting this error.

The error happened in the codition when I try to compare `[lang.identifier intValue] == [[wordDic objectForKey:@"language"]intValue]`.

The error just happened on my iPad. In the iPhone it is working propertly.

What is happening?

```
for (NSDictionary * wordDic  in wordsJson) {
    for (WSLanguage * lang in langs){
        if ([lang.identifier intValue] == [[wordDic objectForKey:@"language"]intValue]) {
            for (WSCategory *cat in cats) {
                if ([cat.identifier intValue] == [[wordDic objectForKey:@"category"]intValue]) {
                    WSWord *word = [self importWord:wordDic withLanguage:lang andCategory:cat];
                    [words addObject:word];
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

This is the WSLanguage class

```
@class  WSLanguage;

@interface WSCategory : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * identifier;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) WSLanguage * language;

@end
```

Comment: What is the reason of the exception? What are the types of `identifier` and the value for key `language`?

Comment: seems not all of `lang` exists in `wordDic`.

Comment: i haven't got any exception, i made a breakpoint for all exceptions but the exception is not throwed and the console said nothing.

The types of identifier is NSNumber and language in wordDic is NSCFNumber  * (long)1

Comment: in the iphone works propertly, just falls on iPad

Comment: If the underlying value in `NSNumber` is `long` you should use `integerValue` rather than `intValue`

Comment: ok, i will try, thanks

Comment: Finally I solved the problem changing the property "NSNumber * identifier" of WSSLanguage for int identifier and problem is solved. I don't need "NSNumber", "int" is fine so.. SOLVED   Thanks at all